# Deriving stochastic process trajectory integral variance

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose the process $x_t=u_t+v_t\int\limits_{0}^tg_t\,dW_t$ is given. Here $W_t$ is the standard Wiener process, $u,v,g$ are some deterministic funcions, and $g$ is such that the integral is well defined. What I am interested in is the integral $I_t=\int\limits_0^tx_sds$, or, more precisely, it's distributional properties. I see it is the normal random variable, since $x_t$ is a gaussian process. What I need is $Var\bigl[I_t\bigr]$. Is there an elegant way to derive it in a closed form?

I see, that $I_t$ is the limit of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x_{k}\Delta s_k$, and thus $Var[I_t]$ is the limit of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}Var[x_k](\Delta s_k)^2+2\sum\limits_{k<l}\Delta s_k\Delta s_l\, \mathrm{cov}(x_k,x_l)$, where both $Var[x_k]$ and $\mathrm{cov}(x_k,x_l)$ can be derived in a closed form, but this seems to be a bulky derivation.

Comment: Hing: Using stochastic Fubini write
$$
I_t=\int_0^tu_s\,ds+\int_0^tv_s\int_0^sg_u\,dW_u\,ds=\int_0^tu_s\,ds+\int_0^tg_u\int_u^tv_s\,ds\,dW_u\,.
$$
This is imho the proper way to show that $I_t$ is Gaussian and should put you in a position
to calculate $\mathbb E[I_t^2]$ (hence the variance) by using Ito isometry.

Comment: Ah stochastic Fubini, yes, I done it. Thank you!